# What causes the default Apache page to open up when the Moodle site is loaded

Tags: apache, web-services, server, ubuntu-18.04, moodle

My site `www.site.com` loads apache2 'It works' page instead of the expected home page of moode which is located at `/var/www/html/moodle`. There is an index file `index.php` inside moodle directory but it is not taken by default. If I go to `www.site.com/moodle` the site homepage comes. The configuration file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf` is enabled. How to solve this?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.com
    ServerAlias site.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/moodle
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.site.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} 
    [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by changing the line

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

to

```
DirectoryIndex index.php /moodle/index.php
```

in the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site.conf`.

**Source :**
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html